# Python: zip two lists together without truncation

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
frame = ["mercury", "noir", "silver", "white" ] 
seat_colors = [ 
            "coconut white", "yello", "black", "green", "cappuccino", 
            "orange", "chrome", "noir", "purple", "pink", "red", 
            "matte", "gray", "bermuda blue" 
                                            ]
```

I'm trying to combine them to a single list where every frame is uniquely matched with every seat color.

I'd like to use `zip()` like so:

```
In [3]: zip(frame, colors)

Out[3]:
[('mercury', 'coconut white'),
 ('noir', 'yello'),
 ('silver', 'black'),
 ('white', 'green')]
```

But it truncates to the length of the smallest list.

I know I can iterate through the lists with:

```
In [5]:

for f in frame:
    for c in colors:
        print "%s, %s" %(f, c)

Out [5]:
mercury, coconut white
mercury, yello
mercury, black
mercury, green
mercury, cappuccino
mercury, orange
mercury, chrome
mercury, noir
mercury, purple
mercury, pink
mercury, red
mercury, matte
mercury, gray
mercury, bermuda blue
noir, coconut white
noir, yello
noir, black
noir, green
....
```

But I'd like the to be smarter about it and use the power of python's built in functions.

#### Any ideas how to use zip ( or something like zip ) and avoid truncation?

Comment: Wait, so do you want the two lists zipped or do you want the Cartesian product?

Comment: @DSM Cartesian product. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`itertools.izip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) to keep zipping until the *longest* sequence has been exhausted.

This uses a default value (defaulting to `None`) to stand in for the missing values of the shorter list.

However, your output is creating the *product* of two lists; use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for that:

```
from itertools import product

for a_frame, color in product(frame, seat_colors):
    print '{}, {}'.format(a_frame, color)
```

The two concepts are quite different. The `izip_longest()` approach will produce `len(seat_colors)` items, while the product produces `len(seat_colors) * len(frame)` items instead.

Comment: Great answer, I did want the product of the two lists. Thanks for reading my mind :).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
for item in itertools.product(frame, seat_colors):
    print item
```

This produces the same results as your nested for loops.